# Store dropdown value permanently in localstorage even if the function is called based on $interval concept

Tags: json, angularjs, angular-local-storage

I have an dropdown which sets the value and content through JSON. The function is called on change which used to store value of dropdown in localStorage and starts the $interval in every short time of period.

you can check the fiddle `here` http://jsfiddle.net/19k99h03/1/

so the issue is that i am able to store value when i choose one of the option from dropdown but it is not able to store more than the time period which i have given. After some period of time the value gets change in localStorage. I want to store the value permanently till i choose another option from the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your views but i have solved my issue.

you can check over `here` http://jsfiddle.net/19k99h03/3/